# What is C# equivalent for the Java Enumeration type? Refer to the code below

Tags: c#, java, enumeration

```
public Enumeration getLogEntries(String header)
{
    return log != null ? ((Vector)log.get(header)).elements() : null;
           //log is a hashtable
           //
}
```

This what I have tried in C#, but it's not complete:

```
public IEnumerator getLogEntries(string header)
{
    return log.Keys.GetEnumerator(); //Something is missing here!
    //log is Dictionary<string,List<string>>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't return the `IEnumerator`, return the `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLogEntries(string header)
{
    return log != null && log.ContainsKey(header) ? log[header] : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Then you iterate over it:

```
foreach(string entries in GetLogEntries("someKey"))
{ 
  //do something
}
```

This also has the advantage of being strongly typed.

There are also `IList<string>` and `ICollection<string>`. depending on what you want to do with your data and if you plan on `.Add`ing to them.

The `Enumerable` static class can be found in the `System.Linq` namespace, if you never heard of linq before, [LINQ Query Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) is a good read. For me, LINQ changed the way I look at sequences.

Comment: Thanx Femaref! but how about the line of code following the the question mark in the java code? is it the one equivalent to the foreach loop?

Comment: I added the equivalent. Note that you don't need to check for `null`, if the `logs` field doesn't exist, and empty sequence is returned, the `foreach` won't be executed at all.

Comment: Cool! what about the parameter header? Anyway it looks like i have about Enumerable class. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is (roughly) equivalent to `Iterable` in Java, similarly `IEnumerator` is equivalent to `Iterator`.

The following is an equivalent C# version of your method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLogEntries(string header)
{
    if (log != null && log.ContainsKey(header))
    {
        return log[header];
    }
    return null;
}
```

As an aside C# uses [Pascal case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for method name as opposed to Java's [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms).